# PostgreSQL Select Arrays with order

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a 'route' table describe as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE NEW_ROUTES (
    id        integer primary key,
    path      integer[],
    name      text
);
```

And I added some rows:

```
insert into NEW_ROUTES (id,path,name)
values (1, '{1,2,3,4}', 'path1');

insert into NEW_ROUTES (id,path,name)
values (2, '{1,2,3,4,5}', 'path2');

insert into NEW_ROUTES (id,path,name)
values (3, '{5,4,3,2}', 'path3');

insert into NEW_ROUTES (id,path,name)
values (4, '{2,3,1,7}', 'path4');

insert into NEW_ROUTES (id,path,name)
values (5, '{7,6,5,4,3}', 'path5');

insert into NEW_ROUTES (id,path,name)
values (6, '{1,2}', 'path6');

insert into NEW_ROUTES (id,path,name)
values (7, '{2,1}', 'path7');

insert into NEW_ROUTES (id,path,name)
values (8, '{2,7,5,1,9}', 'path8');
```

1. How can I select multiple rows, which have integers 1 and 2 and
   where 2 is placed before 1 (for example, {2,1} and {2,7,5,1,9}
   etc..).
2. Which type of index should i use (for example, GIN)?
3. Is there another and best way to solve this problem (for example, using string, json, tree or smth else)?

I will be appreciated if you help me.

Comment: And even if i add such row: insert into NEW_ROUTES (id,path,name)
values (9, '{2,7,5,1,2,9}', 'path9') - i wanted to get this row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Try to use idx function, that return index of element or 0 if it dos't contained.

`select * 
    from NEW_ROUTES
    where
    '{1}' &> path
    and '{2}' &> path
    and idx(path, 2) < idx(path, 1)`

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/intarray.html

To use idx function You should enable 'intarray' module as described in  https://www.postgrespro.ru/doc/contrib.html

2. GIN index is faster to search than a GiST index, but slower to build or update; so GIN is better suited for static data and GiST for often-updated data.
3. you could try to optimize this query if you store hash table with node id as a key, and index in path array as a value. To do it, You mast add another column and calculate index of each node in path one time

Comment: ERROR:  function idx(integer[], integer) does not exist
LINE 4: idx(path,2) < idx(path,1);
        ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

********** Error **********

ERROR: function idx(integer[], integer) does not exist
SQL state: 42883
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
Character: 32

Comment: Is it possible to use not in procedure?

Comment: How Can I know the order of rows if i will use var. 3?

Comment: 1. You should enable 'intarray' module as described in  https://www.postgrespro.ru/doc/contrib.html
3. To do it you mast add another column and calculate index of each node in path one time

Comment: Thanks. Which type of index should i use if i choose first variant?

Comment: @ИванВолынчук GIN index is faster to search than a GiST index, but slower to build or update; so GIN is better suited for static data and GiST for often-updated data.